# Problem in coding with function in python: Base 2 & 10 integer palindrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, palindrome, multiple-input

There was a question which asked to write a code, to get continuous integer input from user until a negative integer is input and for each input I should evaluate if it is a palindrome in both base 10 and 2. If yes then print 'Yes' else print 'No'.

For example: 99 = (1100011)base2, both versions are palindrome so it prints 'Yes'

This is a usual elementary method.

```
while 1:
    num = int(input('Input: '))
    if num > 0:
        num1 = str(num)
        if num1 == num1[::-1]:
            list1 = list(bin(num))
            list1.pop(0)
            list1.pop(0)
            n = ''.join(list1)
            if n == n[::-1]:
                print('Yes')
            else:
                print('No')
        else:
            print('No')
    else:
        break
```

But when I tried to type a code using defining a new function it didn't work well. Here following is the code. Can you note what is wrong with this.

```
def palindrome(n):
    n = str(n)
    if n == n[::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def b2_palindrome(n):
    list1 = list(bin(n))
    list1.pop(0)
    list1.pop(0)
    n = ''.join(list1)
    palindrome(n)


while 1:
    num = int(input('Input: '))
    if num > 0:
        if b2_palindrome(num) and palindrome(num):
            print('Yes')
        else:
            print('No')
    else:
        break
```

@dspencer: edited the indentations

Comment: Please make sure the indentation is the same here as in your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not returning the value of the `palindrome` call in `b2_palindrome`

see below:

```
def b2_palindrome(n):
    list1 = list(bin(n))
    list1.pop(0)
    list1.pop(0)
    n = ''.join(list1)
    return palindrome(n)  # <-- added return here
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to note down such a silly mistake I've made.

Comment: no worries, everyone makes silly mistakes! glad you're back in business.